# WiFi stops working every few days

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, android-11

I have an Android 11 smartphone (Sony XQ-BT52). About every two to three days, I experience the following issue: All of a sudden, the phone stops recognizing any WiFi connections. The WiFi symbol shows that WiFi is on in principle, but no network is found. When I try to search for WiFi networks, it either takes forever or it does never return any results.

Most weirdly, when I try to turn WiFi off and on again, it initially shows the WiFi as being on, but if I go to the settings page again, it is shown as off again (see [this video](http://temp.andreas-unterweger.eu/2022_03_02_19.35.58_edit.mp4), approx. 10 MiB). No networks are ever found after this - it even seems that there is no search after this point. The only way to work around the issue so far is to reboot the phone as a whole, which gives me back WiFi connectivity as well as a list of all available WiFi networks immediately for the next few days. However, it is tedious.

This seems to be like a strange bug, but I could not find anything about similar issues. From related questions, I understood that any power saving settings may impact this, so I disabled everything I could for the sake of testing. However, the issue remains. The issue also seems to be unaffected by the charging state of the phone (it happens at 95% in the same way it happens at 30%).

How can I determine the cause of this and, more importantly, how can I fix it?

Comment: I recommend scheduled reboot daily, this is common for embedded devices (like your residential gateway for example)

Comment: @alecxs I do not want to do that - my SIM card requires a PIN code and I do not want to miss any calls because the phone automatically rebooted. All of my previous phones worked perfectly fine with respect to WiFi connectivity, even when they have not been rebooted for weeks on end. This seems like a bug and there must be a fix or at least a workaround.

Comment: you cannot fix yourself only Sony can do that